# Formatting addresses in Trello with single line spacing

Tags: trello, formatting, markdown

How do I use Markdown in Trello to format a simple address where address items are not all on the same line?.

Here's an example address I want to format:

> George Smith 27 Smith Street Smithsville

I can't get it to format properly. It should have "single line" spacing. "George Smith" would be on its own line, followed by "27 Smith Street" on the next and then "Smithsville".

Something like this:

> George Smith
>   27 Smith Street
>   Smithsville

Like a list, but without bullets. I can't work it out.

Answer (score 10):

What you'll need here is to add a double-space, or two spaces, at the end of the line before you hit the Enter.

So in this case, the keys entered would be:

> George Smith<kbd>space</kbd><kbd>space</kbd><kbd>Enter</kbd>
>   27 Smith Street<kbd>space</kbd><kbd>space</kbd><kbd>Enter</kbd>
>   Smithsville

Markdown requires the addition of those two spaces at the end to mark a new linebreak.

Comment: This was previously broken on Trello due do a bug in our markdown library (https://github.com/evilstreak/markdown-js/issues/28)  We've patched our copy to fix this problem.